# Vulkan camera view position quesition

Tags: graphics, vulkan

I am making a scene including a model, a light point and my camera, I set all of them to (10, 0, 10), then I found the camera seems like appearing in (-10, 0, -10)(or the opposite of light and model).

Here is the using code of my camera:

https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/base/camera.hpp (I set "flipY" to true, FIRST_PERSON).

```
camera.setPosition(glm::vec3(10.0f, 0.f, 10.0f));
```

Here is how I set the model:

```
objs[i]->setObjModel(glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(10.0f, 0.f, 10.0f)) * glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f)));
```

And shadow map of light:

```
lights[0].lightPos = glm::vec3(10.0f, 0.f, 10.0f));
glm::mat4 depthProjMat = glm::perspective(glm::radians(lights[0].lightFov), 1.0f, depthzNear, depthzFar);
glm::mat4 depthViewMat = glm::lookAt(lights[0].lightPos, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.f, 1.f, 0.f));
glm::mat4 depthModelMat = glm::mat4(1.0f);
```

If I change the `setPosition` function to let position multiplied by (-1, 1, -1), that every problem solved, but I just wonder Why?